# Why do bandits or other common bad guys constantly attack Geralt in the Wicher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm trying to get a better grasp of the Witcher universe and I've always wondered about one thing: Apparently a witcher is a very powerful superhuman "mutant" that has access to (low-key) sorcery and an enhanced metabolism, has increased senses and is heavily trained in weaponry and physical combat. So why would any sane man challenge or attack a witcher? I understand that wolfs, drowners or vampires don't really think that way but throughout the game Geralt constantly gets attacked or provoked by "common folk" even though he is wearing his wolf school amulet and his eyes clearly give away his witcher identity.

This throws me off since witcher are known to be lesser empathic beings and also  for their superior strength so why would anyone do that (and then obviously get cut in half or beheaded a minute later)? There are several points in the game where people mention that they've heard about Geralt in Dandelions ballads or other legends so it seems that most people know about witchers and their deeds.

An example that completely blew my mind was the quest:

> "Reason of State" where in the end Dijkstra (an overweight elderly men wearing a brace because of his broken leg) attacks Geralt.

I don't understand at all why incidents like this occur. Why are there only 2-3 quests where people acknowledge and respect Geralt's witcher powers and retreat? Is it because Geralt is a more powerful witcher than others and witchers in general aren't as powerful as Geralt or Vesemir makes them look? Or is it because in Redania there is such a big hatred and general disrespect for nonhumans?

Answer (score 11):

Bandits might not necessarily know of Geralt and his deeds and background. This is in the day before the internet and Facebook; access to knowledge of all known Witchers isn't widely available. All the bandits see when you stroll past is a potential mark.

Even if they did know of Geralt, a bandit has a mindset revolving around getting the next meal and being the baddest mofo in town. Meaning, they don't care about risk, they want coin.

It essentially boils down to ignorance and ego.

Plus it feels like in Witcher 3 that the Witchers have a bad name and not respected. This may also lead to thinking they've died out/are in a weak spot. Let's be honest, they're seen as folk that bring the monsters, not fights  them. This could also lead to more attacks on *weak* Witchers

**Edit: Further thoughts**

Geralt does look like an old man, scarred and tattered, he looks like a pretty easy mark. There are people (humans) that have killed Witchers (check lore) and in large groups, bandits could kill Witchers. One false move for Geralt and the bandits win. I think you may be overestimating Witcher ability vs numbers of opponents.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is one interaction with bandits on the bridge, and one of them actually knows about witchers and tries to warn other guys to stay away from Geralt :)

Comment: @arghtype ya know.. I actually can't remember, looks like I just found my excuse to replay Witcher 3 :p